# How to open right instrumental window in 2D animation

Tags: 2d, windows

[image]
I accidently closed it but I don't know how. This window contained materials, render output, everything

Answer (score 0):

You currently have <kbd>2D Full Canvas</kbd> selected in the header bar. Click back on <kbd>2D Animation</kbd> and you should get the full layout back.

[image]